# how can I import other java lib with ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I m searching for a method to add other lib that I need to reach the the final result with my code using in ANTLR4 but I didn't find the right way to do that.

for example (simple example):

code that parses for the word "today" and prints out  the day "Date: month day year" like today ( Date: Jul 17 2017 ) for that I must import `import java.util.*;` .

`grammar Exp;
the_day: 'today';
WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r') -> skip;`

Is there a way to do that directly from the file **.g4** ?  Or I must do that with another way ?
and thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so by injecting some code snippets into the lexer or parser header (depending on where you need the import statement).

This is done via a `@lexer::header{...}` or `@parser::header{...}` code block at the beginning of your grammar.
So if you want to import your library into the parser class you simply have to add the following snippet at the top of your grammar:

```
@parser::header {
    import java.util.*;
}
```